# XSLT Value-of Selected Not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a style sheet for a large XML file. What I want is that if Redlines have occurred then display the item number. Redlines is either true or false and item number is a number.

Redlines is located: underProductDataeXchangePackage/Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem/AdditionalAttributes[1]/AdditionalAttribute[3]
Item Number is located: ProductDataeXchangePackage/Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem/@itemIdentifier

My code is:

```
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:12pt; ">
<b><tr style="font-family:Calibri; font-size: 12pt; ">Redline Manufacture:</tr></b>
</span>
<br/>
<xsl:for-each select="ProductDataeXchangePackage">
<xsl:for-each select="Changes">
<xsl:for-each select="Change">
<xsl:for-each select="AffectedItems">
<xsl:for-each select="AffectedItem">
<xsl:for-each select="AdditionalAttributes[1]">
<xsl:for-each select="AdditionalAttribute[3]">
<xsl:for-each select="@value">
<td style="text-align:left; ">
<span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:12pt; ">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains(.,'tru')">
<xsl:value-of select="string(.)">
</xsl:value-of>
<xsl:value-of select="string('-')">
</xsl:value-of>
<xsl:value-of select="ProductDataeXchangePackage/Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem/@itemIdentifier">
</xsl:value-of>
<br/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</span>
</td>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
<br/>
```

My output shows the correct number of trues (out of 15 item numbers, only 11 show...thats great); however, the item number is blank

Comment: Can you please include some example XML? Enough so that we can check your XSL. Just stating some XPath doesn't verify that that itself is correct.

Comment: The XML file is too large. It exceeds the allowed char. limit

Comment: You don't need to add all of it - add enough so we can see the structure. Your attempts at XPath in your question are not enough and also you've stuck the word `under` at the start of it, making it even harder to understand.

Comment: OK, your XML example is completely at odds with your XSLT and XPath in your question. Don't just delete random elements to make it smaller - make a COMPLETE and VALID version of your XML with the MINIMUM number of elements required to run your XSLT. Right now, your example is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your actual XML this can only be a best guess - I think your XML looks like this:

```
<ProductDataeXchangePackage>
    <Changes>
        <Change>
            <AffectedItems>
                <AffectedItem itemIdentifier="blah">
                    <AdditionalAttributes>
                        <AdditionalAttribute/>
                        <AdditionalAttribute/>
                        <AdditionalAttribute value="tru"/>
                    </AdditionalAttributes>
                </AffectedItem>
            </AffectedItems>
        </Change>
    </Changes>
</ProductDataeXchangePackage>
```

So I think your `xsl:value-of` statement

```
<xsl:value-of select="ProductDataeXchangePackage/Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem/@itemIdentifier" />
```

isn't showing anything because, in all those nested `xsl:for-each`, your context node at that point is going to be the `value` attribute from your last `<xsl:for-each select="@value">`.

Your XPath will need to navigate back up the node tree until it gets to the `AffectedItem` element, and there you can select the `itemIdentifier` attribute, but if you post a sample of your XML structure I can say for sure.

Edit: I've tried with what I think your XML looks like, and if you replace your `value-of` XPath with the following, it will work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../@itemIdentifier"/>
```

It goes up from the `value` attribute to its parent `AdditionalAttribute`, then up to the parent `AdditionalAttributes` and then to the parent `AffectedItem` element, where it can then select the `itemIdentifier` attribute.

But your XSL is pretty bad overall - there are many better ways of doing it using templates. Take some time to read up on it and see if you can improve it.

Comment: Works! You just saved me the last 3 hours of banging my head against a wall.

Comment: Cool - I've added what I think your XML looks like in its basic form, hope it's right. If you can accept this answer as well, it would be great.

Comment: Accepted answer. Have a similar situtation but this time the path of the item is /ProductDataeXchangePackage/Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem/BillOfMaterialMarkups/BillOfMaterialMarkup/BillOfMaterialMarkupRowNew/BillOfMaterialItem/AdditionalAttributes[1]/@AdditionalAttribute[5] but again it shows up blank. Even with the ../../../@@AdditionalAttribute[5]

Comment: @user3158712 the `../../../` selects the `AffectedItem` node - now work out the XPath below that to get to your required node. It looks like you're quite unfamiliar with XPath - get hold of an app that lets you evaluate XPath on an XML document and play around with it to get some ideas of how it works.